# UNIX sort: Sorting something from the clipboard

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, unix

The other day I saw a colleague of mine using sort to sort a number of lines he copied from a text file.

I've been trying to reproduce it myself and I cannot seem to find how.

The requirements are as follow:

- Use sort from command line, plus whatever else you need to add to configure input
- Paste the text to be sorted from the clipboard
- Get the sorted result in the console

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you type `sort -` the command will accept input from stdin. Then you can just paste whatever you want into the console and type CTRL-D to sort it.

Comment: Excellent!
I think that is undocumented in my man page. I've just found out that I can use it with --files0-from=- too

Comment: Yeah, its not in my manpage either. But - is a standard UNIX convention to use stdin as input. Most standard UNIX programs will recognize it as well.

Comment: It's probably not explicitly documented for `sort` because it works for all sorts of UNIX utilities that operate on streams.

Comment: You don't even need the `-`... Just type `sort`, then paste/type in your data and your EOF indicator...

Answer (score 6):

Easy, just type `sort` (or `sort -`) to run on `stdin`, paste your lines, and hit CTRL+D for end-of-transmission to sort.

Comment: OK, so sort without params works too. Thanks. I really think the man page could be improved...

Answer (score 5):

Use [xclip](http://xclip.sourceforge.net/).

```
 xclip -o | sort -
```

Comment: Sad but true. Sometimes third party tools are the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like:

```
xclip -o | sort > /tmp/xclip_temp; xclip -i < /tmp/xclip_temp;cat /tmp/xclip_temp; rm /tmp/xclip_temp
```

It does:

- Stores the sorted input from the clipboard in the `/tmp/xclip_temp` file;
- Puts the sorted input from the file back to the clipboard;
- Prints the sorted value on the console;
- And finally deletes the temp file;

The reason I am using `;` instead of `|` is because pipe works as a parallel process, so if I used just `|` I would be overwriting the value of xclip while it was still being read.

For your convenience, you can add a function in your `~/.bashrc` file, like this:

```bsh
sort_xclip()
{ 
   xclip -o | sort > /tmp/xclip_temp; xclip -i < /tmp/xclip_temp; cat /tmp/xclip_temp; rm /tmp/xclip_temp;
}
```

So you can just type `sort_xclip` when you want to do it again.

PS: After you edit the  `~/.bashrc`, run `source ~/.bashrc`, then the terminal will loads the function you just created.